# How to decode encoded json to HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am using drupal JSON field formatter to encode HTML body field.

I got this result in json

```
"\"\u2022 Big eggplant\r\n\u2022 2 tomatoes cut in slices\r\n\u2022 1 green pepper cut in slices\r\n\u2022 250gm minced meat\r\n\u2022 \u00bdtbsp of salt\r\n\u2022 \u00bdtbsp dried oregano\r\n\u2022 1tsp black pepper\r\n\u2022 \u00bd cup chopped onions\r\n\u2022 \u00bc cup oil to cook the meat\""
```

how can decode it using JS ?

I tried this code but it is not working fine

```
function htmlbody(x){
        var bodi='';
bodi=x.replace('\n', '<br />')                  // Removes all encoded newline characters
bodi=x.replace('\t', '')                  // Removes all encoded tab characters
bodi=x.replace(/(?:\s+)?<(?:\s+)?/g, '<') // Removes any whitespace before or after a tag-start delimiter.
bodi=x.replace(/(?:\s+)?>(?:\s+)?/g, '>') // Removes any whitespace before or after a tag-stop delimiter.
bodi=x.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
return bodi;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to this point?  The code would help, if you did.

Comment: @rfornal I just update my Question for you

Comment: It would be best if you preformatted this on the server, and have JS receive properly formatted data.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I am developing mobile app I can't use PHP

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that what you have is very close ...

Try this ...

```
function htmlbody(x){
  var bodi='';
  bodi=x.replace('\n', '<br />')                  // Removes all encoded newline characters
  // From this point, bodi is corrected version; x has not been changed.
  bodi=body.replace('\t', '')                  // Removes all encoded tab characters
  bodi=bodi.replace(/(?:\s+)?<(?:\s+)?/g, '<') // Removes any whitespace before or after a tag-start delimiter.
  bodi=bodi.replace(/(?:\s+)?>(?:\s+)?/g, '>') // Removes any whitespace before or after a tag-stop delimiter.
  bodi=bodi.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  return bodi;
}
```

You might also take a look at something like this ... **[json2html.com](http://json2html.com/)**